# JQuery - select next tr's th

Tags: jquery

I am having a bit of problem with jQuery. I hope you can enlighten me with this one.

I have a table header that is populated using PHP. Here is the code:

```
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"></td>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup" class="month_header">January</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">February</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">March</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">April</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">May</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">June</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">July</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">August</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">September</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">October</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">November</th>
    <th colspan="12" scope="colgroup">December</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class="header_column_group">
    <?php for ($i = 1; $i < 13; $i++): ?>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Qty Case</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Qty Case Prev Year</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Tot Sales</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Total Sales Prev Year</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Sales Growth</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Forecast</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Reached</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">Mix</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">BO Total</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">BO Previous Year</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">BO Rate</th>
      <th class="header_column_group_<?php echo $i; ?>">BO Growth</th>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </tr>
  </thead>
```

Now, here is the screenshot of the output of the code above:
[image]

As you can see I will generate 12 months header and under that I will just repeat the columns. Hope I explained it clearly.

Now here is what I want to do, if I click the Month header, example: January,
I want to highlight/change  background to red the header under it. (Qty Case, Qty Case Previous Year, Tot Sales).

Now here is my jQuery code for that:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
    $('.month_header').on('click', function () {
      $(this).parent().next('tr').css('background', 'red');
    });
  }
});
```

But, what my code does, is when I click for example, January, it highlight all the header under the months, but really it should highlight only the header under January.. Please see screenshot:

[image]

I hope I explained myself clearly. Hope you can guide me or guide me where to look. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:gt` and `:lt` selector to target element in the range along with index of month header elements

Also, you don't need to iterate over elements to attach the same event:

```
var $headerGroup = $('.header_column_group');
$('.month_header').on('click', function () {
    $headerGroup.css('background-color', '');
    $headerGroup.filter(':eq('+ ($(this).index() - 1)+')').css('background-color', 'red');//-1 to ignore first td with rowspan 2
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou  **Milind**  for the idea, I have used `slice()` function instead. I also removed my for loop. I'll  mark your answer as the correct one.

I finally solved it. Here is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.month_header').on('click', function () {
    var index = $( ".month_header" ).index(this);

    /** January */
    if (index == 0)
    {
      $('.header_column_group th').slice(0, 13).css('background', 'red');
      $(this).attr('colspan',0);
    }
    /** February */
    if (index == 1)
    {
      $('.header_column_group th').slice(12, 25).css('background', 'red');
      $(this).attr('colspan',0);
    }

    /** Another if statement for other monts*/
  });
});
```

Hope this would also help someone.

Comment: Glad it helps. However the approach you have used will require 12 different if conditions. which wont be the case if you use solution i have suggested. basically slice parameters should be computed based on clicked index.

Comment: Oh yes it require 12 if statments.  I guess it still the same, but your solution is much cleaner. That is how :eq works right? However I can't make it work. I would try to incorporate you solution, it is much simple. Thanks again Milind.